# How do I call API from service bus

Tags: asp.net-mvc, microservices, publish-subscribe, azureservicebus, servicebus

I am trying to learn to Build Microservices based app where Microservices would be communicating via some service bus. In my case, I am using Azure Service bus.

With referring to below link an initial system is set up. Messages are reaching to the queue.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-multi-tier-app-using-service-bus-queues

But as next step or mimicking real app, I have OrderAPI to handle the orders.

This is how my WorkerRole class looks like

```
namespace OrderProcessingRole
{
 public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
 {
    // The name of your queue
    const string QueueName = "ProcessingQueue";

    // QueueClient is thread-safe. Recommended that you cache 
    // rather than recreating it on every request
    QueueClient Client;
    ManualResetEvent CompletedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public override void Run()
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Starting processing of messages");

        // Initiates the message pump and callback is invoked for each message that is received, calling close on the client will stop the pump.
        Client.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // Process the message
                    Trace.WriteLine("Processing Service Bus message: " + receivedMessage.SequenceNumber.ToString());
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Handle any message processing specific exceptions here
                }
            });

        CompletedEvent.WaitOne();
     }

     public override bool OnStart()
     {
        // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections 
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;

        // Create the queue if it does not exist already
        string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
        var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);
        if (!namespaceManager.QueueExists(QueueName))
        {
            namespaceManager.CreateQueue(QueueName);
        }

        // Initialize the connection to Service Bus Queue
        Client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, QueueName);
        return base.OnStart();
    }

    public override void OnStop()
    {
        // Close the connection to Service Bus Queue
        Client.Close();
        CompletedEvent.Set();
        base.OnStop();
    }}}
```

I am not sure, how & where should I call the OrdersAPI when service bus is in place.

I am guessing it would be in

```
OnStart() -> 
Client.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>
            {
                try
                {
                   //Order API call here
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            });
```

If my guess is right, then how I call my OrderAPI which is hosted on

```
http://localhost:8090/api/order
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `OrdersAPI` is your Web API endpoint receiving requests from a browser, it would construct Azure Service Bus messages and send to a queue. Your Worker Role then would receive those messages and process. Processing would not be performed in Web API.

Answer (score 0):

The Orders API should be called inside

```
Run() -> 
Client.OnMessage((receivedMessage) =>
            {
                try
                {
                   //Order API call here
                }
                catch
                {

                }
            });
```

Use HttpClient for triggering the API. By doing this, the API will be called whenever a message is received from the Queue.

As the worker role is hosted in Azure environment, the APIs hosted somewhere public can only be called from here. It does not identify the API hosted in local machine. Try hosting the API in [Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/app-service/) or [Azure Function App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/functions/).